# Is signed integer overflow in safe Rust in release mode considered as undefined behavior?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow, llvm-codegen

Rust treats signed integer overflow differently in debug and release mode. When it happens, Rust panics in debug mode while silently performs two's complement wrapping in release mode.

As far as I know, C/C++ treats signed integer overflow as undefined behavior partly because:

1. At that time of C's standardization, different underlying architecture of representing signed integers, such as one's complement, might still be in use somewhere. Compilers cannot make assumptions of how overflow is handled in the hardware.
2. Later compilers thus making assumptions such as the sum of two positive integers must also be positive to generate optimized machine code.

So if Rust compilers do perform the same kind of optimization as C/C++ compilers regarding signed integers, why does *The Rustonomicon* states:

> No matter what, Safe Rust can't cause Undefined Behavior.

Or even if Rust compilers do not perform such optimization, Rust programmers still do not anticipate seeing a signed integer wrapping around. Can't it be called "undefined behavior"?

Comment: I'd say 1. has a subtle error in assumption: compilers *can* know how overflow is handled in hardware. C code however, cannot, since it can run on hardware with different handling.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Is integer overflow in safe Rust in release mode considered as undefined behavior?

**No**. It is well defined as 2's complement wrap. In debug mode, it will panic.

---

> **Q:** So if Rust compilers do perform the same kind of optimization as C/C++ compilers regarding signed integers

Rust does not. Because, as you noticed, it cannot perform these optimizations as integer overflows are well defined.

For an addition in release mode, Rust will emit the following LLVM instruction (you can check [on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=68add9881de6cf1223a5dd823c61df53)):

```
add i32 %b, %a
```

On the other hand, clang will emit the following LLVM instruction (you can check via `clang -S -emit-llvm add.c`):

```
add nsw i32 %6, %8
```

The difference is the `nsw` (no signed wrap) flag. As specified [in the LLVM reference about `add`](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#add-instruction):

> If the sum has unsigned overflow, the result returned is the mathematical result modulo 2n, where n is the bit width of the result.
>
> Because LLVM integers use a two’s complement representation, this instruction is appropriate for both signed and unsigned integers.
>
> `nuw` and `nsw` stand for “No Unsigned Wrap” and “No Signed Wrap”, respectively. If the `nuw` and/or `nsw` keywords are present, the result value of the add is a poison value if unsigned and/or signed overflow, respectively, occurs.

The poison value is what leads to undefined behavior. If the flags are not present, the result is well defined as 2's complement wrapping.

---

> **Q:** Or even if Rust compilers do not perform such optimization, Rust programmers still do not anticipate seeing a signed integer wrapping around. Can't it be called "undefined behavior"?

"Undefined behavior" as used in this context has a very specific meaning that is different from the intuitive English meaning of the two words. UB here specifically means that the compiler can assume an overflow will never happen and that *if* an overflow will happen, any program behavior is allowed. That's not what Rust specifies.

However, an integer overflow via the arithmetic operators *is* considered a bug in Rust. That's because, as you said, it is usually not anticipated. If you intentionally want the wrapping behavior, there are methods such as [`i32::wrapping_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.i32.html#method.wrapping_add).

---

Some additional resources:

- [RFC 560](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/26197104b7bb9a5a35db243d639aee6e46d35d75/text/0560-integer-overflow.md) specifies everything about integer overflows in Rust. In short: panic in debug mode, 2's complement wrap in release mode.
- [Myths and Legends about Integer Overflow in Rust](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2016/04/myths-and-legends-about-integer-overflow-in-rust/). Nice blog post about this topic.

Comment: When the C Standard uses the term Undefined Behavior, it means nothing more nor less than that no requirements are imposed by *the Standard*; the authors of the Standard have expressly said that UB "identifies areas of conforming language extension".  The Standard would allow compilers to make the inferences you describe in cases where that would be genuinely useful, but makes no attempt to judge whether they are, nor to forbid them in cases where they would be worse than useless.  Instead, it expects compiler writers to know customers' needs better than the Committee ever could.