# What happens in Rust programming language when an integer arithmetic operation overflows?

Tags: rust, integer-overflow

As far as I know, in C programming language(and many C - based languages), when an arithmetic operation overflows over an N-bit integer, this overflow shortens the result to modulo N-th power of 2,
retaining only the LSB's of the resultant.

What happens when such an integer arithmetic operation overflows in Rust programming language.

Comment: The first sentence of your question isn't the full picture. Signed integer overflow in C is undefined behaviour, and unsigned overflow is modulo the max value of the type (which is not necessarily the same as what you claim, due to things like padding bits being permitted).

Comment: Heavily related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60238060/is-signed-integer-overflow-in-safe-rust-in-release-mode-considered-as-undefined

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you’re compiling in debug mode, Rust includes checks for integer overflow that cause your program to panic at runtime if this behavior occurs.

When you’re compiling in release mode with the `--release` flag, Rust does not include checks for integer overflow that cause panics. For signed values the result is based on two's complement wrapping. For unsigned values the result is modulo the maximum value of the type + 1.

The standard library has a number of functions for more control over what should happen in an overflow case, e.g., [`checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_add), [`wrapping_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.wrapping_add), and some other variations.

If you haven't already, I suggest reading [The Rust Programming Language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/), which has a [section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch03-02-data-types.html#integer-overflow) addressing this specifically.

Comment: Out of curiosity: isn’t inserting runtime checks at every single arithmetic operation super costly, both in program size and in running time? (for running time, I guess you benefit from branch prediction heavily, but still)

Comment: It certainly has a runtime cost (which is one of the reasons other than optimisations why Rust debug builds are generally quite comparatively slower than C -O0 builds). While there's some overhead for program size I wouldn't say its too much of a concern given the size is also heavily driven by debug symbols. Of course, if you want to avoid this you can just build a release binary.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Rust Reference, chapter "Behavior not considered unsafe"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/behavior-not-considered-unsafe.html#integer-overflow):

> ### Integer oveflow
>
> If a program contains arithmetic overflow, the programmer has made an error. In the following discussion, we maintain a distinction between arithmetic overflow and wrapping arithmetic. The first is erroneous, while the second is intentional.
>
> When the programmer has enabled `debug_assert!` assertions (for example, by enabling a non-optimized build), implementations must insert dynamic checks that `panic` on overflow. Other kinds of builds may result in `panics` or silently wrapped values on overflow, at the implementation's discretion.
>
> In the case of implicitly-wrapped overflow, implementations must provide well-defined (even if still considered erroneous) results by using two's complement overflow conventions.
>
> The integral types provide inherent methods to allow programmers explicitly to perform wrapping arithmetic. For example, `i32::wrapping_add` provides two's complement, wrapping addition.
>
> The standard library also provides a `Wrapping<T>` newtype which ensures all standard arithmetic operations for `T` have wrapping semantics.
>
> See [RFC 560](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0560-integer-overflow.md) for error conditions, rationale, and more details about integer overflow.

So, depending on your compiler settings, your program may panic or silently wrap when overflowing. Depending on either of those behaviors is not a good idea. If you need to handle the possibility of overflow, use either wrapping functions to explicitely tell the compiler that you want and expect overflows to wrap back, or use checked methods like [`u32::checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.checked_add) to handle overflow manually.